# overloading qt properties

Tags: qt, properties, metaobject

I've got a property of a custom type.

```
class foo : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Custom x READ x WRITE set_x)

public: 
    void set_x(Custom &x) { /*whatnot*/}
}
```

QJson effectively invokes the following dynamic assignment:

```
((QObject*)&foo_instance)->setProperty("x", QVariant(QString("something-from-json")))
```

which returns false, as documented in the Qt:

*If the value is not compatible with the property's type, the property is not changed, and false is returned.*

How can I shim this into my Custom value? Clearly defining a side-function `void set_x(QString)` or `void set_x(QVariant)` cannot possibly work, since the property system would be unaware of this accessor.

Also, where is the type compatibility checked? - the program control never reaches

`int foo::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)`

the function generated by the meta-object compiler..

How can I make `Custom` compatible with these types?

Comment: The comment to the accepted answer actually nails it down for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be useful to read [The Property System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html)

Especially *Properties and Custom Types* part.

If to be brief, all properties save as QVariant.
You need to use [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) macro to make your *Custom* type compatible with Qt properties.
And after that you have to call [qRegisterMetaType](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType) function to register your type.

Comment: Yes, I've read this part of the documentation - the problem starts with defining the WRITE accessor - it needs to be of type Custom (or Custom& or Custom*, IIRC) - but I'm getting the setProperty dynamic caller to shove QVariant(QString).value() into there. There is a Custom(QString) creator, but I can't get the setProperty to invoke it either statically or dynamically. And declaring the WRITE accessor typed set_x(QVariant &v) doesn't help either - it's not being called.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have only one way to do it - use QString property. And if you need you can convert QString to Custom type into setter.